# How to create a dummy column and populate with an array after joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pg

I have 3 tables

Table 1 **landing_modules**

- l_id
- l_name
- l_module
- l_variant
- l_version

Table 2 **categories**

- c_id
- c_name

Table 3 **category_landing_modules**

- l_id
- c_id

`l_id` and `c_id` being foreign keys from `table_3` to `table_1` and `table_2` respectively. Now the needed output is

All the rows from `landing_modules`, which will be

```
SELECT * FROM  landing_modules;
```

But additionally I want a column in result set as `category_ids`, which should contain the corresponding `c_ids(category_ids)` from `table_3 - category_landing_modules`.

The result set will look something like

- l_id
- l_name
- l_module
- l_variant
- l_version
- c_ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT lm.*,
       ARRAY(SELECT clm.c_id
                    FROM category_landing_modules clm
                    WHERE clm.l_id = lm.l_id) c_ids
       FROM landing_modules lm;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want `array_agg`:

```
select
  l.l_id, l.l_name, l.l_module, l.l_variant, l.l_version,
  array_agg (cl.c_id) as c_ids
from
  landing_modules l
  left join category_landing_modules cl on
    l.l_id = cl.l_id
group by
  l.l_id, l.l_name, l.l_module, l.l_variant, l.l_version
```

Comment: Yes, that's a solution too. It only has the problem, as it stands, that if there is a landing module not assigned to any category the query will produce an array with a single `NULL` like `{NULL}` instead of an empty array. To fix that a `CASE` expression can be used to check for such a `{NULL}` array and replace it with an empty one `{}`.